# I run the python's turtle module then I want to see the output on the sypder's output screen, my computer doesnot respond to me?

Tags: python, screen, spyder, turtle-graphics

I don t see any problem when I run simple codes such as creating a turtle. However, when I try OOP via turtle library code and specific classes, the code output neither works nor responds to my commands. Then kernel dies and python restarts.

Answer (score 0):

I use both anaconda base spyder and PC. PC uses 3.9 python version, spyder uses 3.8.5. Probably I have to delete spyder.